# Edit config file using bash and sed

Tags: bash, sed

Assume `test.txt` contains:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');
/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');
/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
```

I'd like to edit the above file using a bash script. I'd run the script and replace `'wordpress'` with `'foobar'` say. Here's what I've got thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Database config
echo -e "\ndatabase name: \c"
read DB_NAME

sed -i "s/^\define\('DB_NAME',\s*'(.*\$)'\);/\1$DB_NAME/" "C:/Apache24/htdocs/test.txt"
```

Running the script and the `test.txt` *does* get modified, although not in a way I'm trying to achieve. In fact, nothing changes in the file whatsoever.

What's a correct regexp for search and replace used in conjunction with `sed` for the above constants?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I've spent most of the afternoon on it?

Comment: Your question is of the form "*here's some random code, it doesn't work lol*". You could improve it by going over each part separately, explaining what you think it does (maybe including links to the manual). At that point you could then verify each part to make sure your understanding matches reality. And then you'd have debugged it yourself and could ask a much better question.

Comment: You are trying to match a literal `$` in the old value.

Comment: `sed 's/wordpress/foobar/' file`?

Comment: @melpomene +1 for the pedagogy tips, lol.

Comment: @chepner - so your saying `$DB_NAME` fails to get expanded out to a variable preventing it from inserting into the target file?

Comment: @Cyrus - That would work although we would have to know in advance that the string `'wordpress'` existed.

Comment: @cookie No, I'm saying you aren't matching `wordpress` in the first place, because `.*\$` doesn't match it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i "s/define('DB_NAME', '.*');/define('DB_NAME', 'foobar');/" file
```

Comment: And with this I could easily replace `'foobar'` with a variable `"$FOOBAR"` say. Brill and thanks

Comment: Interesting how the period and astrix both work wrapped in double and then single quotes here :).